# kinect joint coordinate values change in opposite way

Tags: kinect, kinect-v2

After I place a Kinect 2 and stand in front of it, I moved my arm up in front and down (e.g. forward flexion).

Then, I found my y-coordinate of the wrist joint that changes large (0.17) to small (0.11) and to around (0.16).
I found this strange, because in the Kinect guide, positive y-axis indicates upward direction.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973078.aspx

it seems like we should have larger value of wrist-y coordinate when we place a arm up direction.
I am getting the opposite results. Anyone can comment on this?

Q. Are we supposed to get decreasing y-value of wrist when is moving upward direction?

Q. If not, can anyone have any ideas why this happens?

Q. In addition, I found my the other side of wrist (left) has negative value. Can anyone comment why left side of wrist has negative value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because of the Kinect v2 reference system. The center of the sensor corresponds to (0,0,0) - x,y,z.

If you make movements to the left or right in the X and Y axis, it is logical to have negative values.

The origin (x=0, y=0, z=0) is located at the center of the IR sensor on Kinect
X grows to the sensor’s left
Y grows up (note that this direction is based on the sensor’s tilt)
Z grows out in the direction the sensor is facing
1 unit = 1 meter

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn785530.aspx

Hope this helps you.